# PHP reference acting strange

Tags: php, post, reference, foreach

I'm having a strange problem with PHP's reference(&).

Let's say I have a form that looks like:

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post">
   Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
   Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
   Location: <input type="text" name="location" /><br />
   Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phonenumber" /><br />
</form>
```

And then I submit that form to another PHP handler. And the handler does this:

```
foreach($_POST as $name => &$value)
{
    //more code here
}
echo $_POST['phonenumber']; //Returns value of $_POST['location'] for some reason
```

Can someone explain to me why the value of phone number would be the value of whatever location is? Even if there is no code inside of the foreach it still does this.

EDIT:

For those of you wondering what is going inside the foreach, or why I'm even doing this, it's because it's a clean way to escape all the data submitted to the handler, instead of doing it one variable at a time manually, especially when you have dynamic input coming in. So like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $name => &$value)
{
    $value = preg_replace( "/[<>#$%]/", "", $value);
    $value = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $value);
}
```

It works beautifully except for the problem I stated above.

Comment: could it be the way $_POST is constructed? try assign it to your own array and then running the foreach (with reference) on that array.

Comment: *Even if there is no code inside of the foreach it still does this.* What?

Comment: From my point of view, impossible. What PHP version do you use?

Comment: Do you assign to `&$value` later, or do you perform this loop multiple times with the same name? (Basically, looping like this is terrible in PHP and really hurts so try not to do it.)

Comment: Standardly what you are experiencing shouldn't happen, however using references in a foreach can be rather confusing. Do you happen to have any other occurances in the same scope of $value? tbh, seeing more of the code would help.

Comment: If you are using $value by reference inside that loop, please do not omit the code inside that loop, it seems highly relevant to me...

Comment: The code inside the loop is not relevant. I've deleted it and it still does the same thing - hence the last sentence in my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you perhaps iterating it twice, once with a reference and once without? It makes a big difference:

```
$array = [1, 2];

foreach($array as &$value);
echo implode(',', $array); # 1, 2

foreach($array as $value);
echo implode(',', $array); # 1, 1
```

[And here's a demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/XdSCU3) The fix is to [unset `$value` between the loops](http://codepad.viper-7.com/akmBSC):

```
$array = [1, 2];

foreach($array as &$value);
echo implode(',', $array); # 1, 2
unset($value);

foreach($array as $value);
echo implode(',', $array); # 1, 2
```

Comment: You nailed it on the head. I was iterating twice, once with a reference and once without. Using unset worked.

Comment: Okay.  Why does this make a difference?  Why does getting $value from the array by reference cause it to survive outside of the loop's scope?

Comment: @DanielBingham: PHP doesn’t have loop scope. `&$value` still references the last item in the array after looping, so assigning to it (as a `foreach` loop *does* in PHP) will change the last item. To sum up: PHP is weird.

Comment: @minitech: So loop variables always remain in scope past the loop?  It just doesn't matter when they're assigned by value instead of reference since they're just overridden on the next use?  Probably good to keep in mind for memory issues.

Comment: It's kind of anomaly. I don't think PHP works this way in a for loop though.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you are getting confused by the value by reference in your `foreach` loop. Another reason why you just shouldn't use it. If you really think you need it at least `unset()` the `value` after the loop. Check out this example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/VCOI2O (note the `&` at phonenumber in the first dump, it is still referenced).

But I seriously think you should reconsider doing it by reference. Instead just access the item you need in your loop:

```
foreach($_POST as $name => $value)
{
    // do with the value what you want
    $_POST[$name] = $value;
}
```

However it would be even better to not change the `$_POST` superglobal at all. It will only confuse other people and yourself when you try to access it later on and something has been changed in it.

Comment: You were right. I needed to use unset. Read my edit above for my reasoning for using the reference.

Comment: As I stated it is still not prefered to do it by reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reassiging the `$value` variable, this could happen. For example, in this case, the last iteration (for phone number) will equal the location value because the `&` means that the value will be updated if you assign to it:

```
<?php

$i = 0;

foreach($_POST as $name => &$value) {
    if ($i > 2) {
        $value = $temp;
    }
    $i++;

    $temp = $value;
    echo $value;
}

?>
```